# Convert an XML to a different XML using XSLT and remove empty tags

Tags: xml, xslt

am slowly learning the XSLT coding.. Need a help/advice.. 
I have scenario here where I need to generate an xml with newnode1 using XSLT by reading an xml node1 and also remove any empty tags if any from the output XML. Here is how my xml looks like..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Node>
   <Node_1>
     <Line>1</Line>
     <Text>First node1</Text>
     <Desc>Desc1</Desc>
     <Cust>Cust1</Cust>
     <Value1/>
 </Node_1>
 <Node_1>
     <Line>2</Line>
     <Text>First node2</Text>
     <Desc>Desc2</Desc>
     <Cust>Cust2</Cust>
     <Value1></Value1>
 </Node_1>
 <Node_2>
     <Line>1</Line>
     <ReadInd>Y</ReadInd>
     <WriteInd>Y</WriteInd>
     <UpdateInd>Y</UpdateInd>
     <Value2/>
 </Node_2>
 <Node_2>
     <Line>2</Line>
     <ReadInd>N</ReadInd>
     <WriteInd>N</WriteInd>
     <UpdateInd>N</UpdateInd>
     <Value2/>
 </Node_2>
 </Node>
```

This is how my XSLT code is right now,

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="node2" match="Node_2" use="Line" />

  <xsl:template match="/">   
   <xsl:for-each select="Node/Node_1">
    <node>
    <line><xsl:value-of select="Line"/></line>
    <text><xsl:value-of select="Text"/></text>
    <desc><xsl:value-of select="Desc"/></desc>
    <cust><xsl:value-of select="Cust"/></cust>
    <val1><xsl:value-of select="value1"/></val1>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('node2', Line)">
        <subnode>
        <readind><xsl:value-of select="ReadInd"/></readind>
        <writeind><xsl:value-of select="WriteInd"/></writeind>
        <updateind><xsl:value-of select="UpdateInd"/></updateind>
        <val2><xsl:value-of select="value2"/></val2>
        </subnode>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </node>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>    
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I have another XSLT code to remove the empty tags,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">     
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">                              
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">                              
        <xsl:if test="(not(.=&apos;&apos;) and not(.=0))">    
            <xsl:copy>                                            
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there a way I could do the XML to XML conversion and also remove the empty tags in a single XSLT code..

Comment: What empty tags? Please set up a reproducible example with the empty tags and fix original XML as well since closing *Value* tags are incorrect.

Comment: I have corrected the input XML to have valid ones with my questions.. Please check now.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by empty tags (i.e., my first question).

Comment: By empty tags, i meant those XML tag elements which has no values..
like , <Value1/> or <Value1></Value1>

Answer (score 0):

Consider a dynamic solution without writing out all node names and condition xpath queries to filter out empty text with `[text()!='']`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="node_key" match="Node/*" use="Line"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Node">
    <nodes>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('node_key', Line)[1])]"/>
    </nodes>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Node/*">
    <xsl:variable name="curr_line" select="Line" />
    <node>        
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[text()!='']"/>       
        <subnode>
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::Node_2[Line = $curr_line]/*[text()!='']"/>
        </subnode>
    </node>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQw)